# Mistake in matching basemap through contextily

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, contextily

I am focusing on visualizing some datasets of Switzerland through 'contextily' package in python. (Here is just the sample. In fact, the whole dataset has 16000 records in Switzerland.)

|  | Unnamed: 0 | User_location_code | Twitter_created_time | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 226333 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 23 | 4488879 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (47.3744489, 8.5410422) |
| 28 | 3772151 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (47.1486137, 8.5539378) |
| 35 | 3226920 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.4978958, 9.8392428) |
| 51 | 4577072 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.2131843, 6.0815756) |
| 55 | 4464950 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.4602978, 6.8418655) |
| 65 | 173633 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.2767572, 6.168958) |
| 86 | 4670064 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.2922522, 7.5323195) |
| 89 | 529343 | CH | 1/1/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 90 | 879080 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (47.2617701, 8.4197059) |
| 100 | 4195443 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 106 | 1837089 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 109 | 4392712 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (46.4705779, 6.8436858) |
| 110 | 4191284 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (46.6932583, 6.4611912) |
| 112 | 3581491 | CH | 1/2/2018 | (47.3744489, 8.5410422) |
| 129 | 4238370 | CH | 1/3/2018 | (46.5332403, 9.874586) |
| 146 | 3103734 | CH | 1/4/2018 | (46.4602978, 6.8418655) |
| 147 | 3103733 | CH | 1/4/2018 | (46.4602978, 6.8418655) |
| 179 | 4531534 | CH | 1/6/2018 | (47.4634767, 7.8125639) |
| 184 | 207311 | CH | 1/6/2018 | (47.0505452, 8.3054682) |
| 194 | 974817 | CH | 1/6/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 205 | 4623486 | CH | 1/7/2018 | (46.4978958, 9.8392428) |
| 214 | 2782686 | CH | 1/7/2018 | (46.9886931, 6.8906893) |
| 221 | 4394683 | CH | 1/8/2018 | (46.5218269, 6.6327025) |
| 223 | 586320 | CH | 1/8/2018 | (47.31874, 7.6698284) |
| 229 | 787444 | CH | 1/8/2018 | (47.4991723, 8.7291498) |
| 238 | 1615538 | CH | 1/9/2018 | (46.6356963, 6.5320717) |
| 248 | 543950 | CH | 1/9/2018 | (47.4250593, 9.3765878) |
| 249 | 1005935 | CH | 1/9/2018 | (47.3744489, 8.5410422) |
| 252 | 4217738 | CH | 1/10/2018 | (46.1839156, 6.1224047) |
| 269 | 411809 | CH | 1/11/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 271 | 1661548 | CH | 1/11/2018 | (47.33490645, 9.163183508014553) |
| 279 | 814333 | CH | 1/12/2018 | (46.6356963, 6.5320717) |
| 286 | 652801 | CH | 1/12/2018 | (47.3744489, 8.5410422) |
| 293 | 591620 | CH | 1/13/2018 | (46.2231863, 6.2242767) |
| 297 | 4378107 | CH | 1/13/2018 | (46.4978958, 9.8392428) |
| 301 | 2356500 | CH | 1/13/2018 | (46.5939043, 7.9078016) |
| 308 | 652799 | CH | 1/13/2018 | (47.3744489, 8.5410422) |
| 315 | 649442 | CH | 1/14/2018 | (46.6583588, 7.6965086) |
| 319 | 4380071 | CH | 1/14/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 320 | 190831 | CH | 1/14/2018 | (46.5032766, 6.6867879) |
| 321 | 4384644 | CH | 1/14/2018 | (46.4602978, 6.8418655) |
| 325 | 4629311 | CH | 1/14/2018 | (46.647529399999996, 7.080368826694413) |
| 339 | 411808 | CH | 1/16/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 341 | 2783072 | CH | 1/16/2018 | (46.5218269, 6.6327025) |
| 344 | 4395955 | CH | 1/16/2018 | (46.6789116, 7.1027113) |
| 348 | 4394190 | CH | 1/16/2018 | (46.2017559, 6.1466014) |
| 354 | 440279 | CH | 1/17/2018 | (46.7410614, 7.2193275) |
| 358 | 4397447 | CH | 1/17/2018 | (46.7899498, 7.2183078) |

Because of the geographical coordinate in meter, I decided to use the 'EPSG:3857' as the CRS.

```py
# Load the environment
import numpy
import pandas
import geopandas
import pysal
import seaborn
import contextily
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the dataset
CH_points = gpd.read_file('CH_points04.shp')

# Print out the crs of the dataset
print(CH_points.crs)

CH_points_3857 = CH_points.to_crs("epsg:3857")

# Print out the crs of the dataset
print(CH_points_3857.crs)
```

However, I met a mistake during the basemap time. Specifically, in the following code, I have finished the preliminary visualization about the dataset that I used.

```py
# Generate scatter plot for quick checking
seaborn.jointplot(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", data = CH_points, s = 2.0);
```

The result is here, it works well.

And then, I consider using the function 'contextily.add_basemap()' to make kde-plot looks better, at least **in Switzerland**.

```py
# Set up figure and axis
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 10))
seaborn.kdeplot(
    CH_points_3857["X"],
    CH_points_3857["Y"],
    n_levels=50,
    shade=True,
    alpha=0.55,
    cmap="viridis_r",
)
# Add basemap
contextily.add_basemap(
    ax, crs = CH_points_3857.crs.to_string(), source=contextily.providers.OpenStreetMap.CH
)
# Remove axes
ax.set_axis_off()
```

The result is here. As you see, it can load the basemap, not bad, right? But the basemap now is in France, **not in Switzerland**.

How can I align these properly?

Note:
For pictures, you could see here. https://github.com/geopandas/contextily/issues/212

For the dataset, you could find it here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c85ofyiHKDxjyV5m9LgvWNWL_E9fiifb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide the data 'CH_points', 'CH_points_3857'?

Comment: Did you mean to include a result? Also, is the data actually in EPSG:3857 or does it need to be transformed? Please include a full [mre] e.g. using sample points so we can help debug.

Comment: @OriYarden Thanks a lot. I have edited the question again. And I think you could download the dataset now.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado In fact, without enough reputation of stack overflow, I cannot upload the pictures into here. However, thanks for your suggestions, I have edited the description of my question now.

Comment: @Xiaoyan Lan can you manually type out (all or a subset of) the Ch_points and include it in the question? I can't seem to open the files in the link.

Comment: @OriYarden I have tried to upload the subset of the dataset. However, I need to say that if there are just 50 records in Switzerland, it is easy to show all of them. After all, there are more than 15000 Swiss records in the original dataset. Meanwhile, around 10000 records are clustered in three detailed areas. I guess this is why it cannot work directly at the zoom level set by 'contextily'.

Comment: The 'contextily.providers.OpenStreetMap.CH' has bound: [[45, 5], [48, 11]] which ranges from Lyon, France to Germany, and knowing that contextily can be finicky, perhaps providing a more specific source url could resolve this, such as 'url=image.getMapId(params)["tile_fetcher"].url_format' using import ee.

Comment: @OriYarden Thanks a lot, Ori. I will use another specific URL to replace this one and try again. Have a nice day.